# Heap dump with jmap throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, jvm, jmap

I'm trying to take a heap dump using jmap but I keep getting a NPE.
I'm using Oracle's Java7 jdk (details below).

```
$sudo jmap -F -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin 21966

Attaching to process ID 21966, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 24.71-b01
Attaching to process ID 21966, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 24.71-b01
Dumping heap to /tmp/dumps/2015-02-18T13:24:36Z-heap.bin ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:197)
  at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:128)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.writeSymbolID(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:905)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.writeFieldDescriptors(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:743)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.writeClassDumpRecord(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:511)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.access$000(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:297)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter$1.visit(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:446)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.SystemDictionary$2.visit(SystemDictionary.java:179)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.Dictionary.classesDo(Dictionary.java:69)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.SystemDictionary.classesDo(SystemDictionary.java:190)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.SystemDictionary.allClassesDo(SystemDictionary.java:183)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.writeClassDumpRecords(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:443)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.write(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:413)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.run(HeapDumper.java:56)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:221)
  at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.main(HeapDumper.java:77)


$java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

Has anyone seen this before? Googling brings up an issue with OpenJDK (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028623)
but I'm not sure if the Oracle JDK has the same problem.

Comment: Do you have to use -F to take your dump? My experience is that the Java tools are much more robust if you can avoid using -F.

Comment: You're right. I didn't need the -F option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you've found the correct link to the exactly same issue.
It has been fixed in JDK 7u72.

BTW, `-F` options makes `jmap` work in completely different way.

- without `-F` jmap connects to the target JVM using [Dynamic Attach mechanism](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#battach) and then asks JVM to produce the dump on its own from within JVM process;
- with `-F` jmap uses [Serviceability Agent](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#bsa) to suspend the target JVM process and then reads its memory remotely, doing all the work in a separate process. While SA is a cool and a powerful tool, it is not maintained very well to be 100% compatible with up-to-date JVM implementation details. So, it is not an uncommon thing to encounter an issue with SA.

Comment: I managed to get this working by:
  
1. Removing the -F option.  
2. Running jmap as the user who owns the process.  
3. Fiddling about with the directory permissions where the file is created (e.g. chmod o+w /tmp/dumps).  

Thanks v much!

Comment: The only question I have is: when using the Dynamic Attach Mechanism, suppose the jvm is busy doing GC or is otherwise occupied (I had a GC threshold exceeded), will it still respond to a request for Heap Dump? In that case, will I have to use the '-F' option ?

Comment: @Rajiv Yes, the disadvatange of Dynamic Attach is that JVM may not respond if it is busy with long-running GC or something. `-F` is exactly for these situations. Otherwise Dynamic Attach is faster and more reliable.